# Create Table of Equations & Import Them with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

### The Setup

Have a table of equations (on right) that are static. If actually implemented, the equations posted will have cell references and be a little more complex

---

### The Goal

I would like to be able to import the equations onto the left table with `=VLOOKUP(C2, F:G, 2, 0)`. In this instance, it will return `=Average(5, 10)`. **However, instead of returning this as text, I would like it to evaluate the equation and return that result (7.5)!!**.

Any idea how to accomplish this (strictly seeking spreadsheet solution)? I'm not sure if this is possible without manual intervention (paste as text and re-enter cell which does force a calculation)

[image]

The fromulas on the right table are all prefixed with a coma so excel will not evalulate them. I.E.

- `'=Average(5, 10)`
- `'=SUM(5, 10)`
- `'=F4+F6`
- `'SQRT(9)`

I have also tried `SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(), "'", "")` to get rid of the prefix, but this still just returns the equation as text.

---

### The Avoidance

Each region will require a already tedious equation to get to the correct result. For this reason, I do not want to create 4 nested `IF` statements. Making any changes to the results will require people to study the equation to most likely fail on first attempt.

Comment: If you can use VBA, then the `Evaluate` method will do this.  Just create a UDF that will evaluate the formula to return a result, and nest the VLOOKUP inside your UDF so that it grabs the correct formula and then evaluates it.  If you can't use VBA, then the manual method you've already described will be your best bet.

Comment: **strictly seeking spreadsheet solution**. With VBA this is simple. Hoping there is some quirky way to force this without the manual solution I mentioned. Each region requires unique rigor and I do not want to create 4 helper columns or have a ridiculously long series of `IF(IF(IF(.....`. @tigeravatar I fear you are correct though, but would like to let this stew and see if anything unique pop ups!

Comment: Perhaps the second answer listed here: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Comment: With how you're mentioning that there are many complex formulas, I'm wondering if there's an XY problem going on

Comment: I already have the nested IF written and it works as expected. I’ve done my due diligence to simplify - but each region has 3 unique & separate possible outcomes. It seems a helper column for each region may be the best non-VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be moving away from Vlookup, and into nested if's. If you're small enough, you can do it. I like using alt+enter to break everything over lines, so it's readable, and it allows for sliding cell references:

```
=If(Cell1=Criteria1,Formula1,
If(Cell1=Criteria1,Formula2,
If(Cell1=Criteria3,Formula3)))
```

Etc.

The EVALUATE function in Excel got removed because it was a security hole, and you could exploit it to hijack a computer without the security features picking it up.

If you don't want to do this, you could have a table where you computer all of your criteria, then your if statement selects the result you want. More calculations, but the formulas are a bit simpler.

Edit: If your formulas are VERY simple, you could get away with using `=Subtotal`, and return the type of formula you're looking for. For example, if it was an average, your source table would have a `1`, and your formula would be =Subtotal(Vlookup(),Range)

Comment: Thanks for the response and interesting tidbit about EVALUATE. Unfortunately, the equations for each region are complicated which is why I am looking to explore this route. Nested IF statements is the normal route, but that equation would loop and loop and loop

Comment: Some results will be text & some will be numeric so the `Subtotal` does not work